# span inside a button tag not clickable using selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to click and "Add Course" labelled button using selenium webdriver but it is not working out for me.

Here's the snippet I took from chrome developer tools:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-green" onclick="javascript:AddCourse();">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign">
          ::before
    </span> 
    <span translate="portallang_addCourse" class="open-sans ng-scope">
          "Add Course"
    </span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need one of the following xpaths:

First choice:

```
//span[contains(text(), 'Add Course')]
```

These two, only if there are always 2 spans and the second span is always Add Course:

```
(//button[@class='btn btn-green']/span)[2]
//button[@class='btn btn-green']/span[2]
```

Slowest option as the entire document is scanned. Add Course can only occur once on the page:

```
//*[contains(text(), 'Add Course')]
```

Answer (score 1):

What error are you getting? What property did you use to click on the span element?

You got to use xpath for such elements.

Use **xPath Finder add-on for Chrome** and extract the unique xpath for this element:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-helper/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl?hl=en

You can always write an unique xpath manually but this just saves time and is accurate.

Hope this helps!

Comment: When I tried this:        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Add Course']"));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Add Course']"));
This is the error I'm getting: Exception in thread "Thread-0" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //button[contains(text(),'Add Course'] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//button[contains(text(),'Add Course']' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: Xpath is wrong in many levels. First of you have not mentioned span in xpath. Also, "Add Course" is NOT the text of button or span. 

Try something like this, try a longer xpath. I can only write below xpath with the provided info: 
**//button/span[2]**